# r - append one table to another if they share the same value in a column

Tags: r

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1:5), b = c(6:10), c=c("df1","df1","df1","df1","df1"))
df2 <- data.frame(a = c(1,3,5,7,9), b = c(16:20), c=c("df2","df2","df2","df2","df2"), d= LETTERS[1:5], e= LETTERS[6:10])
```

I would like to create a new table that does following:

1. stack one table on top of the other only if the value in column a matches (i.e. 1,3,5 only)
2. show only columns a, b, and c (ignore columns d and e)
3. in total there should be 6 rows and 3 columns, with rows 1-3 from df1 (a=1,3,5), and rows 4-6 from df2 (a=1,3,5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### base R

```r
common <- intersect(df1$a, df2$a)
rbind(
  subset(df1, a %in% common, select = a:c),
  subset(df1, a %in% common, select = a:c)
)
#    a  b   c
# 1  1  6 df1
# 3  3  8 df1
# 5  5 10 df1
# 11 1  6 df1
# 31 3  8 df1
# 51 5 10 df1
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(
  semi_join(df1, df2, by = "a"),
  semi_join(df2, df1, by = "a")
) %>%
  select(a, b, c)
#   a  b   c
# 1 1  6 df1
# 2 3  8 df1
# 3 5 10 df1
# 4 1 16 df2
# 5 3 17 df2
# 6 5 18 df2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `semi_join()` from `dplyr` package.

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1:5), b = c(6:10), c=c("df1","df1","df1","df1","df1"))
df2 <- data.frame(a = c(1,3,5,7,9), b = c(16:20), c=c("df2","df2","df2","df2","df2"), d= LETTERS[1:5], e= LETTERS[6:10])

library(dplyr)
new_df <- rbind(semi_join(df1,df2,by="a")[,c(1:3)],semi_join(df2,df1,by="a")[,c(1:3)])
new_df
```

Semi-Join: Returns all rows from `df1` where there are matching
values in `df2`, keeping just columns from `df1`. Its a filtering join.

Output:

```
> new_df
  a  b   c
1 1  6 df1
2 3  8 df1
3 5 10 df1
4 1 16 df2
5 3 17 df2
6 5 18 df2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `merge` and `split.default` :

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = 'a')

result <- subset(do.call(cbind.data.frame, 
                 sapply(split.default(df3, sub('\\..*', '', names(df3))), 
                        unlist, use.names = FALSE)), select = a:c)
result

#  a  b   c
#1 1  6 df1
#2 3  8 df1
#3 5 10 df1
#4 1 16 df2
#5 3 17 df2
#6 5 18 df2
```